# How do you use an if statement to stop a calculation in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a form where a user will input the number of `jobs` they did for a day as well as the `km` they travelled. Upon inputting those 2 fields, the `km` field is divided by the `job` field to output a value to another field call `km_jobcard`. The issue is that if someone did 0 jobs for the day, the calculation cannot occur because you cannot divide by 0. Is there anyway to use an if statement or any other method to fill that field as none or give an output that's logical in the DB if this `job` field is 0?

My controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // $energy = new Maintenance;
    $energy = new VehicleLog();
    $request->validate([
        'start_odo' => 'required',
        'end_odo' => 'required|gt:start_odo',
    ]);

    $energy->jobcard_count = $request->input('jobcard_count');
    $energy->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
    $energy->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');
    $energy->km = $request->input('end_odo') - $request->input('start_odo');
    $energy->km_job = ($request->input('end_odo') - $request->input('start_odo')) / $request->input('jobcard_count');
    $energy->km_job = number_format($energy->km_job, 2);
    $energy->save();
    return redirect('/vmaintenance')->with('success', 'data added');
}
```

My view:

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Job Cards Completed:</label>
  <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="jobcard_count" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" min="1" required>
  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Additional comments:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" rows="3" placeholder="Enter additional comments here" name="comments"></textarea>
</div>

      <div class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;">
        <label for="recipient-name" style="width: 7em"class="col-form-label">Start dODO</label>
        <input type="number"style="width: 7em" name="start_odo" class="form-control" id="start_odo" min="0" onchange="document.getElementById('end_odo').min=this.value;" required>
      
      </div>
    
      <div class="mb-3" style="float:left;"style="margin-left: 200px;">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">End ODO</label>
        <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="end_odo" class="form-control @error('end_odo') is-invalid @enderror" id="end_odo" min="document.getElementById('start_odo').value"  required>
        @error('end_odo')
        <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
    @enderror
   
      </div>
```

Comment: what's stopping you to use a ``conditional statement`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if($request->input('jobcard_count') > 0) {    
    $energy->km_job = ($request->input('end_odo') - $request->input('start_odo')) / $request->input('jobcard_count');
} else {
    $energy->km_job = 0; // or 'none'
}
```